# Modificar la Cinta de Opciones de Excel Añadiendo Pestañas, Grupos y Botones

Tags: excel, vba

Para Excel.
Tengo 3 Libros de macros.
Mi deseo es que al abrir cualquiera de ellos, en la Cinta de Opciones, solo se ven las macros que contiene ese libro. No lo consigo.
Aunque entre en el libro, Alt+F11 y no vea las macros de otros libros, si clico en alguno de los botones que veo de otro libro, se lanza la macro

Y mi deseo, más completo, sería poder , mediante código VBA añadir Pestañas, Grupos y Botones, asignándoles las macros que contiene ese libro.

Al parecer hay una aplicación muy completa de Fernando Andreu, que permite descargarla y mediante un exe auto instalarse en Excel, pero lo que quiero no es tener la maravilla gratis. Lo que quiero es APRENDER.

El código mas cercano que tengo, y no es mio, es:

```
Sub AddMacroToRibbon()
'Add a button to the ribbon that executes the MyMacro macro

Dim cmdBar As CommandBar
Dim cmdButton As CommandBarButton

Set cmdBar = Application.CommandBars("Ribbon")

Set cmdButton = cmdBar.Controls.Add("CommandButton", "MyMacro")
cmdButton.Caption = "MyMacro"
cmdButton.OnAction = "MyMacro"

End Sub
```

Y falla en al linea: Set cmdButton = cmdBar.Controls.Add("CommandButton", "MyMacro")

... y no se  el porqué,

Se agradecerían ideas para poder hacerlo por los dos medios: A mano o por código

Comment: Buscar por `Add-in`, creo que es lo que estas buscando